# Where did lcdui go, in JME SDK 3.0+?

Tags: java-me, lcdui

I want to write a tiny "hello world" J2ME MIDlet. In a sample like [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/SimpleMidletDemo.htm), classes in `javax.microedition.lcdui.*` are used for display output.  When I try to compile it in Eclipse, I get the error,

> The import javax.microedition.lcdui cannot be resolved

I've installed JME SDK 3.4, and I'm able to run MIDlets that don't import javax.microedition.lcdui.*. I read somewhere that lcdui can be obtained from the wireless toolkit; and [Oracle says](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html) that the wireless toolkit has been integrated into JME SDK as of 3.0+.

So why can't Eclipse find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I know the answer now.

I got back to the JME SDK 3.4 documentation page on [Using Sample projects](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.4/ecl/html/runsamples.htm#CJAJGJIH), and created and ran an instance of UIDemo. It uses lcdui classes, but it runs flawlessly - no errors about inability to resolve `javax.microedition.lcdui.*`.

The difference appears to be that the working sample uses different libraries than the one I tried at first. The first one uses org.elipse.mtj.JavaMEContainer/Oracle Java(TM) Platform Micro Edition SDK 3.4/**IMPNGDevice1**,
while the one that works uses org.elipse.mtj.JavaMEContainer/Oracle Java(TM) Platform Micro Edition SDK 3.4/**JavaMEPhone1**. They contain different sets of jars, e.g. the working one contains `midp_2.1.jar`, while the earlier one has `impng_1.0.jar`.

A follow-up question might be, why doesn't IMP-NG have lcdui in it? Well, those who pay attention to what they're doing will have [read that](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=228)

> This JSR [for IMP-NG] will define a J2ME profile targeting embedded networked devices that wish to support a Java runtime environment similar to the Mobile Information Device Profile (MIDP) version 2.0, but that do not provide the graphical display capabilities required by MIDP 2.0.
>
> The Information Module Profile - Next Generation (IMP-NG) will be a strict subset of MIDP 2.0, where at least the APIs relating to **GUI functionality (the LCDUI) are removed.** Functionality not already present in MIDP 2.0 is not anticipated or desired. "

The next question might be, why did I end up selecting IMP-NG when I was going through the tutorial... when I really do want a MIDlet that does something graphically? But I'm not sure I care, now that it's working.

Answer (score 0):

The new me sdk 8.2, as I understood after browsing all class and in packages,  does not provides any class to develop user interface. not like sdk 3.4, that have many graphical components.